# Tensorflow Dataset Interleave Image File Paths for Reading

Tags: tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to use the tensorflow Dataset API to load tif images that can be on network storage. The map_func I pass to the tensorflow.Dataset.interleave function is not passed the string filename I expect, but instead a tensor with dtype string.

I have tried evaluating this tensor using sess.run and tensor.eval() (also passing in the current session as the session parameter), but tensorflow raises a ValueError: "ValueError: Fetch argument  cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Tensor Tensor("arg0:0", shape=(), dtype=string) is not an element of this graph.)
or("arg0:0", shape=(), dtype=string) is not an element of this graph.)".

An example of my tensorflow data pipeline

```py
class DataLoader:

...

    def setup(self):

        ...

        tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
            (
                self.training_filenames, # a python list of strings
                self.training_label_filenames # a python list of strings
            )
        )
        .apply(tf.data.experimental.filter_for_shard(
            self.shard_count,
            self.shard_index))
        .repeat()
        .shuffle(buffer_size=self.training_data_shuffle_buffer_size)
        .interleave(
            lambda data_filepath, label_filepath: (
                self.preprocess_training_data(data_filepath, label_filepath)
            ),
            cycle_length=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE,
            num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
        )
        .batch(self.training_data_batch_size)
        .prefetch(self.training_data_batch_size)

        ...

    def preprocess_training_data(self, data_filepath, label_filepath):
        data = tifffile.imread(self.session.run(data_filepath).decode())
        data_resize = (self.training_data_shape[0], self.training_data_shape[1])
        data_transpose = (1, 0, 2)
        data_scale = 255.0
        data_dtype = self.training_data_type.as_numpy_dtype()

        data = numpy.transpose(
            cv2.resize(data, data_resize), data_transpose
        ).astype(data_dtype) / data_scale

        label = tifffile.imread(self.session.run(label_filepath))
        label = numpy.transpose(
                    numpy.expand_dims(
                        cv2.resize(
                            label,
                            data_resize),
                        2
                    ),
                    data_transpose
                )

        weights = [
            self.vec_class_weights(current_label)
                .astype(self.label_data_type.as_numpy_dtype())
            for current_label
            in label
        ]

        return data, label, weights
```

I expect my preprocess_training_data function to be passed strings, or I would be able to evaluate the tensor my function is passed from the dataset interleave transformation which would evaluate to a string.